# how to remove trailing zeroes from a string not number php

Tags: php

I need to update table by removing trailing zeroes comes after a . in a string.
For example, consider the strings like `5x115.30`,`5x115.700`,`5x115.00`,`5-115.00`.
i know the floatval function. But it not working for a string like this. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm thinking RegEx will help you with this. But I'm not that good at it to give you the correct expression.

Comment: Is `5x115.30,5x115.700,5x115.00,5-115.00` a single string ? or is it example of four different string?

Comment: its example of 4 different strings

Answer (score 0):

[preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to rescue....

```
<?php

$string1 = '5-115.000';
$string2 = '5.030x00115.7010';

$string1 = trim(preg_replace('#(\.[\d]*?)[0]+([\D]|$)#', '$1$2', $string1), '.');
$string2 = trim(preg_replace('#(\.[\d]*?)[0]+([\D]|$)#', '$1$2', $string2), '.');

print_r($string1);
print_r($string2);
```

Output :

```
5-115
5.03x00115.701
```

Regular Expression Explanation:

```
\.[\d]*?)[0]+$

\.        => this will ensure we only replace parts which starts with a . (dot)
[\d]*?    => this means any digit such as 0-9, *? makes it optional (any amount of digit can be there or not, it doesn't matter to us)
[0]+      => here we are defining that we match literal 0 . + sign makes it to match multiple zeros
([\D]|$)  => this group indicates either end of the string or any character other than numbers, so we only replace trailing zeros.
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, Will it also replace the other digits after zero? eg, string '5x115.07'. So in this case will the out be like '5x115'?

Comment: @harry, thanks for pointing that out. yup there was a flaw in my regex, and i **fixed** it.  `$` sign at the end of regex will ensure to only replace trailing zeros.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, can i use this regex for string like 5.030x00115.700? the output like 5.03x00115.7?

Comment: hmm, let me think a bit.  But I think you **shouldn't** handle this type of float value as string. there can be mis-calculation any time.

Comment: @SarathSRajendran ,  Updated the code again...check now. :)